# bt_adapter_le_start_scan() scans other than BLE devices too in tizen wearable native application

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app

I am developing tizen wearable native application, in which I only needs specific BLE devices to be scanned.
So, I am scanning BLE devices with the help of bt_adapter_le_start_scan(). But this method returns both BLE and other 
Bluetooth devices too. I don't want other than BLE devices to be scanned, because if I have more bluetooth devices near me
it is taking lots of time to scan that BLE devices. As name suggest bt_adapter_le_start_scan() should only look for BLE devices.
I can filter out these BLE devices but it is taking lots of time to scan that specific BLE devices.

So, how can I restrict bt_adapter_le_start_scan() to only scan for BLE devices?
or is there any way to send UUID(Bluetooth device identifier) to scan function which will only scan for specified devices 
in quickest way?

Answer (score 0):

Tizen API provides **scan_filter** feature to filter scan.

[bt_adapter_le_scan_filter_create](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/4.0.0/org.tizen.native.wearable.apireference/group__CAPI__NETWORK__BLUETOOTH__ADAPTER__LE__MODULE.html#gad2d2dc95f4985ddd8704733e51b6490f) (bt_scan_filter_h *scan_filter) : Creates a scan filter to find only LE advertisements which match specific requirements.

Scan Filter can be set based on various Properties: Device Address, Device Name, service UUID, Manufacture data , type, etc.
There are different functions to set the scan_filter. Documentations:

[Tizen Wearable 4.0 Bluetooth LE Adapter API References](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/4.0.0/org.tizen.native.wearable.apireference/group__CAPI__NETWORK__BLUETOOTH__ADAPTER__LE__MODULE.html)

[bt_adapter_le_scan_filter_set_type()](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/4.0.0/org.tizen.native.wearable.apireference/group__CAPI__NETWORK__BLUETOOTH__ADAPTER__LE__MODULE.html#gadc9b52fdf04609096036b3def5527406)  function seems relevant.

But, This feature starts from Tizen **4.0**, Right now If you are working with Tizen Wearable **3.0** or below there are functions to **get_scan_results** based on property like:
Device Name, service UUID, Manufacture data, Bluetooth LE packet type, etc. There are different functions to get_scan_results. Documentations:

[Tizen Wearable 3.0 Bluetooth LE Adapter API References](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/3.0.0/org.tizen.native.wearable.apireference/group__CAPI__NETWORK__BLUETOOTH__ADAPTER__LE__MODULE.html)